# How to get a type from a union where each type has an id

Tags: typescript, types

in my typescript app:

I have sevral sensors and each of them has a unique metric type (like an id) and the type of the value of the metric is unique to each sensor:

```
type SensorAMetric = {
    sensorId: 'ABC',
    value: [number, number]
}
type SensorBMetric = {
    sensorId: 'DEF',
    value: { foo: string, bar: number }
}
type Metric = SensorAMetric | SensorBMetric
```

When I receive a metric from my webSockets, I store it inside an object where keys are spensor ids

```
const metrics: {
    'ABC': SensorAMetric[],
    'DEF': SensorBMetric[]
} = {...}
```

I managed to be less specific by typing `metrics` like so

```
const metrics: { +readonly [Property in Metric['sensorId']]: (Metric & { sensorId: Property })[] } = {...}
```

But I can't find a way to write a function `getSensorMetrics(sensorId)` where the type of the return depends on the sensorId.

Here is what I've tried

```
function getSensorMetrics(id: Metric['sensorId']): (Metric & { sensorId: typeof id })[] 
{
    return metrics[id]
}
```

But I have this result:

```
getSensorMetrics('ABC')[0].value // [number, number] | {foo: string, bar: number}
```

Instead of :

```
getSensorMetrics('ABC')[0].value // [number, number]
```

Comment: Package it in a `struct`, with one member of struct being an `enum` , the value of the enum determines the type last updated in the `union`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the `id` parameter in `getSensorMetrics()` is explicitly of type `Metric['sensorId']`, which is a [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types).  And `typeof id` is just that union; it is nothing narrower than that.  So your return value will also be of the full union type.

If you want `id` to possibly be seem as some *subtype* of `Metric['sensorId']`, then you should make `getSensorMetrics()` [*generic*](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) in the type of `id`.  Like this:

```
function getSensorMetrics<T extends Metric['sensorId']>(id: T) {
  return metrics[id];
}
```

Now we have a type parameter `T` corresponding to the type of `id`.  It is [constrained](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) to `Metric['sensorId']`, so you know it has to be something assignable to that type.  But when you call `getSensorMetrics("ABC")` the compiler will infer `T` to be `"ABC"`.

You can see that this works as expected:

```
const sensorMetrics = getSensorMetrics('ABC');
const two = sensorMetrics[0].value.length; // okay
```

So that's fine and we could end here if we want.  From here on out there are just changes that I think improve things for callers but are not necessary, at least for the example code posted here.

---

If you inspect the return type of `getSensorMetrics()` inferred by the compiler, you'll see it leaves a little something to be desired:

```
/* function getSensorMetrics<T extends "ABC" | "DEF">(id: T): {
    readonly ABC: (SensorAMetric & {
        sensorId: "ABC";
    })[];
    readonly DEF: (SensorBMetric & {
        sensorId: "DEF";
    })[];
}[T] */

const sensorMetrics = getSensorMetrics('ABC');
/* const sensorMetrics: (SensorAMetric & {
    sensorId: "ABC";
})[] */
```

That is accurate, but probably not what you want people to see.

If you have a union `Metric` and you want to pick just the member(s) of that union with a `sensorId` of type `T`, you should probably use [the `Extract<T, U>` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#extracttype-union).  Your version with an [intersection](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types) is conceptually the same, but the compiler doesn't always reduce intersections in nice ways (so you'd end up with `SensorAMetric & {sensorId: "ABC"}` instead of `SensorAMetric`).

So you could improve this a bit by changing the definition of `metrics`:

```
const metrics: { +readonly [K in Metric['sensorId']]: 
  Extract<Metric, { sensorId: K }>[] 
} = null!

function getSensorMetrics<T extends Metric['sensorId']>(id: T) {
  return metrics[id];
}
/* function getSensorMetrics<T extends "ABC" | "DEF">(id: T): {
  readonly ABC: SensorAMetric[];
  readonly DEF: SensorBMetric[];
}[T]*/

const sensorMetrics = getSensorMetrics('ABC');
/* const sensorMetrics: SensorAMetric[] */
```

So that's definitely nicer at the end.  I'm thinking that the IntelliSense of the return type for `getSensorMetrics()` is still a bit busy, since it spells out the type of `metrics`.  We can just annotate the return type using `Extract` directly, like this:

```
function getSensorMetrics<T extends Metric['sensorId']>(
  id: T
): Extract<Metric, { sensorId: T }>[] {
  return metrics[id] as Extract<Metric, { sensorId: T }>[];
}

const sensorMetrics = getSensorMetrics('ABC');
/* const sensorMetrics: SensorAMetric[] */
```

That's better.

Note that I used a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) to tell the compiler that `metrics[id]` is of the expected return type.  The compiler isn't good at understanding when a specific value (like `metrics[id]`) is assignable to a type that depends on an unresolved generic type parameter, so you often need to assert it.  This is a current limitation of TypeScript; see [microsoft/TypeScript#33912](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33912).  The sort of analysis you'd hope to see where, say, `T` is narrowed to each of `"ABC"` and `"DEF"` in turn and inspected against `metrics[id]` for each case does not happen; single lines like `metrics[id]` get analyzed once, and so the compiler sometimes loses correlations between different expressions of union type; see [microsoft/TypeScript#30581](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581).

Okay, I'd better stop there.

---

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAyhB2BnA9gJwIIFkLFQSwGMoBeKAbwCgopEEVUBJAEwC4oBydAIQGF2AaKlABuAQwA2AVwhsA2vEkBbAEYRU-KApVqAuhQC+FUJFh00XbLkIlyQ2kjTM27ACIBRAGIChYqTPJQAGbIyGyIVvAA5hrKoqhsWqqoUIaGxtCW+ESkcA4YmdYAPqZ5FjhZFJVV8KKKEIhgogTQDPCBarbUBMhIwFB1VgSIbGRQANSoEKJMPeIgULIACqjIkKigUHjwUAUEsuz29MzsOjpsABS7UABkAYeOrFDLq2ob+gCUsjopNgri4gBCSrUQKSeAEYB4HpQSI4XL0XaIAA8ABUoBAAB7ABBMRA7cqEfb3RhME4APnOeEeKPenWoUEmwEkqG2AyyiFkVJ0AG4hIZqAB6ABUQTBEKh21hwHhaERqPRWJxeIARNweMqoMVle4PMqKVS2DSRkJ6QypjN4HMoGqLjL8gSiLdKKaXTQzCS2KreMrea6Pl9fS7JtNZvMdbb3WVBjc6a7qMSnFBtZ4fSb6f6eXzZCjvkKBcCoN1em68oibFK7YjzpxeOx3oHhYWeuESwiHcMoOc7VgHTHnS6E48verAxmoHmC0WW8AAO7IGzExGyAAMOgAdL5pGvxAhIsAABZCAUCpvF2ehKAAJkqhiqFBqdQaTRabTUl7pU76bMIHdGE3NoYLAA0ps2y7ES7rHKcbBuFiqBNMASK7BooyDmwIH6GSXw-KQfyAgWoLgpC0IVu6cpopi2LwLi+KDBBeRQfq1K0v21CMsyrLtpyTCZtQ-JQI2hHiiRcJke28qUUqSZqhqWo6nqlLMcaprBhaVo2iU9A9nRvH0qpgHhpp5jgbp+jZjoE5CJ+rayu25aiaW7bVmqdYNiK1mLu2bDdiZ475lZzZ9OeC5iYMHKrhuEhbjuUQHkeJ7WeebDXgY1S1PUjTNNaiC0OstgBcW35DCM4z6Za8xLCsawbFstFZPRRyktBnZXE6Nkek8VWvPMY76L8kj-ECBFisRkoOW2YUSYq1F4uBByQU1TGGu8MFwQhSEOih7WJmimHYaxZpMiy-RcVyUCiHisG4OtyF3AthopFhplHiKQmjTC422ZNFHTTRw6yUm8lLVARpQFd8EQhtgxbWhIPco92GWV0gXtWWpCkY5YXObW9YvaeLaeWF3nutp9W5v5yNnnOIWY+yK7rpuEDbrucWCglKNJVeN5AA)